# Shrink (not compress) a PDF file using free software

Tags: pdf, export, adobe-fireworks

After designing a document in Adobe Fireworks (I know, not made for it, but hey, legally buying software is expensive) I am able to export it to a PDF. The problem is that I designed it at 300 DPI, but the export is at a lower seemingly hard coded<sup>1</sup> DPI so the exported document is far far bigger than an A4 and there seems to be no setting to change this. Is there a way to shrink - NOT compress (which is the only thing Google is finding) - a PDF file using free software maintaining text as text (PDF printers would otherwise do the job).

---

Footnotes:

1. There is a 'print size' which affects prints and allows me to print a proper PDF, but then I get the text as a graphic.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Please read the question: 'using free software maintaining text as text'. Not that I would't consider an answer that fixes this issue within Fireworks so that I won't need to shrink anything, but I for sure do not want to shrink anything *in* Fireworks.

Comment: [related post on Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1082373?tstart=0)

Comment: A quick search got me [this](https://docupub.com/pdfresize/), which may help you. You would probably be better asking this on [softwarerecs.se] though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ghostscript (if you are not afraid of the commandline). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507511/6770384) presented the basic command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA -sPAPERSIZE=a4 \
   -o fixed.pdf \
   fireworks.pdf
```

Unfortunately, the command will reprocess embedded images, possibly introducing artefacts. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/373740), you can use the following options to keep the original images:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA -sPAPERSIZE=a4 \
   -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged \
   -dDownsampleMonoImages=false \
   -dDownsampleGrayImages=false \
   -dDownsampleColorImages=false \
   -dAutoFilterColorImages=false \
   -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false \
   -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
   -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode \
   -o fixed.pdf \
   fireworks.pdf
```

Check out the original answer for more information and alternative options.

Note for other use cases: Both commands do not seem to preserve PDF-Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no. You can set up your Fireworks document with a canvas size of 21cm x 29cm (A4) and a resolution of 300pdi. However the Adobe Acrobat viewer appears to display (and print) all your document's 300pdi image resolution but at screen resolution, hence the apparent increase in size. The image resolution is only relevant when you print the document, so in the print dialogue box if you choose the 'Fit' or 'Shrink oversize pages' option, you will be printing your 300dpi images at the maximum resolution your printer is capable of - no matter what size paper you are printing to. Tip: for maximum image quality click the export options button and turn off or reduce compression...

[image: Adobe PDF Export Options]